# How to Divide complicated lists

Tags: python, list

I was wondering if you could help me understand how to code a solution to this problem,

I have two lists like this:

```
list1 = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]] 
list2 = [[z1, m1, m2, m3], [z2, m1, m2, m3], [z3, m1, m2, m3]]
```

and my desired output would be:

```
list3 = [[z1, (m1/y1), (m2/y2), (m3/y3)],
         [z2, (m1/y1), (m2/y2), (m3/y3)],
         [z3, (m1/y1), (m2/y2), (m3/y3)]]
```

what I have are 2 list of lists and i want to divide values in list2 (except the first as it's a string) by the second item in each of the lists in list1.

what would the code be to do this? I've tried making for loops to solve it but i haven't found much success.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? Have you tried creating a new list by iterating over the other lists and appending the corresponding values?

Comment: sorry if i wrote badly, my question is how do I take the values in list2 and divide it by the second value in list1,  list3 is meant to be a new list with the end result

Comment: Are `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` also `strings`?

Comment: yes x1, x2 and x3  are also strings

Comment: `[[z, *(m/y for m,(_, y) in zip(ms, list1))] for z, *ms in list2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some rearranging of `list1` items, and then it's just about iteration and tuple unpacking:

```
list3 = []
for ((z1,m1,m2,m3),(y1,y2,y3)) in [[zm, [y for (x,y) in list1]] for zm in list2]:
    list3.append([z1,(m1/y1),(m2/y2),(m3/y3)])
```

Above code can be written also as a list comprehension:

```
[[z1,(m1/y1),(m2/y2),(m3/y3)] for ((z1,m1,m2,m3),(y1,y2,y3)) in [[zm, [y for (x,y) in list1]] for zm in list2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. For the sake of the answer, I have defined variables with appropriate values.

```
x1 = 's'
x2 = 't'
x3 = 'u'

y1 = 2
y2 = 4
y3 = 6

z1 = 'a'
z2 = 'b'
z3 = 'c'

m1 = 4
m2 = 8
m3 = 12

list1 = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]]
list2 = [[z1, m1, m2, m3], [z2, m1, m2, m3], [z3, m1, m2, m3]]
list3 = []

for sub in list2:
    temp_list = [sub[0]]
    for indx, num in enumerate(sub[1:]):    
        temp_list.append((num//list1[indx][1],)) # single-element tuples need a trailing comma

    list3.append(temp_list)

print(list3)

[['a', (2,), (2,), (2,)], ['b', (2,), (2,), (2,)], ['c', (2,), (2,), (2,)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers, if you want some kind of generic way,

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
list2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 8,7,6]]
s_l2=np.shape(list2)
for i in range(s_l2[0]):
    for j in range(s_l2[1]):
            if j!=0:
                    list3[i][j] = list2[i][j]/list1[j-1][1]
```